# 2 Linux Distribution with windows?

Tags: boot

I run Windows 10 and Kali Linux at same GPT HD,
After I setup Ubuntu (i make new partitions  swap ,/ and /home) , i reinstall it and add partition Reserved UEFI , It doesn't boot ?

Comment: Read [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me/399627).

Comment: If u r new user... Just forget about it! I don't even suggest u to install 3 OSes at the same time... specially Kali! Useless... Just install Ubuntu!

Comment: Ubuntu now does not need swap partition, it uses swap file. But will use a swap partition if found. You can only have one ESP - efi system partition per drive. Post link to summary report: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair I have multiple Ubuntu installs, but do not share /home, but share /mnt/data with almost all of my data, but not user config files in /home. Then I can have different settings in each install to test or experiment what I may like without damaging main working install.

Answer (score 0):

You can use as many as OS you need on just 1 System, but it has its own problems! I suggest you to use same SWAP space and /home directory for all of your linuxs (if you are not seperated them when you installed it).

Anyway, my last paragraph is not necessary! if you installed new Linux distribution, and you didn't corrupted UEFI partition, then you just need to go inside one of your linux distros and run this command:

`sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`

It will probably solve your problem.